# Creating RPM and DEB manually

Tags: centos, rpm, deb

I am doing a project with my friends which integrates two opensource web applications into one.  Both applications use a MySQL database.

I want to merge the two into a single RPM or DEB file. So that, everything (creation of database, addition of conf file in apache's conf.d folder, installation menus of both the applications, etc) will get done automatically when a user installs the package.

I had read about alien, a software which converts tar.gz and rpm to deb and viceversa. But it wont be helpful for me I guess. Please suggest me some methods to achieve my aim.

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what you are trying to combine and how. Why is `gdebi package1.deb package2.deb` or `rpm -i package1.rpm package2.rpm` not enough?

Comment: I just need to combine two RPM s so that both will get installed if i install the combined one.

Comment: All you need to do is to make one a dependency of the other.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am really a novice in this RPM building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really beyond the scope of this site. We can't give you a howto on how to build RPMs or DEBs. There are *many*, many resources out there for that. For example, [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) are Fedora's docs on building RPMs.

What you need to do is read that link, understand how RPMs are built and then simply add package2 as a requirement of package1. That way, if your users install `package1`, `package2` will automatically be downloaded/installed from the repositories as well.

Specifically, you need to read the details on the `SPEC file` format. For example, to make mysql a requirement, you would add this line:

```
BuildRequires:      mysql
```